# Python scips executing of a function (CS50x Lab 6: World Cup)

Tags: python, cs50

Currently, I am writing a code on Python to make lab 6 for CS50x. When I am trying to debug my code, it seems just to skip the function simulate_tournament() and produces anything as an output. I would appreciate suggestions on how to debug this code and make the program running:)

My code with the mentioned problem:

```
# Simulate a sports tournament

import csv
import sys
import random

# Number of simluations to run
N = 1000


def main():

    # Ensure correct usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python tournament.py FILENAME")

    teams = []
    # TODO: Read teams into memory from file
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            row["team"]
            row["rating"] = int(row["rating"])
            teams.append(row)

    counts = {}
    # TODO: Simulate N tournaments and keep track of win counts
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        winner = simulate_tournament(teams)
        
        if winner in counts:
            counts["winner"] += 1
        else:
            counts["winner"] = 1

    # Print each team's chances of winning, according to simulation
    for team in sorted(counts, key=lambda team: counts[team], reverse=True):
        print(f"{team}: {counts[team] * 100 / N:.1f}% chance of winning")


def simulate_game(team1, team2):
    """Simulate a game. Return True if team1 wins, False otherwise."""
    rating1 = team1["rating"]
    rating2 = team2["rating"]
    probability = 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((rating2 - rating1) / 600))
    return random.random() < probability


def simulate_round(teams):
    """Simulate a round. Return a list of winning teams."""
    winners = []

    # Simulate games for all pairs of teams
    for i in range(0, len(teams), 2):
        if simulate_game(teams[i], teams[i + 1]):
            winners.append(teams[i])
        else:
            winners.append(teams[i + 1])

    return winners


def simulate_tournament(teams):
    """Simulate a tournament. Return name of winning team."""
    # TODO
    while len(teams) > 1:
        teams = simulate_round(teams)
    return teams[0]["team"]




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try to locate your error more precisely, you had bunch of syntax errors before the edit. I can't check the whole code because I also don't have the files that you are reading.

Comment: The code supposes to take as an input a csv file and run simulations of the FIFA World Cup. The full description of the task is here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/labs/6/ . csv file contains the name of the country in the first row and its scorer in the second row. When I am running a program, it shows an empty output and I can print anything in a terminal. I appreciate your readiness to help:)

Comment: At a quick glance, this `while i < N` is an infinite loop since the value of `i` never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you don't increment i your while loop?

```
i = 0
while i < N:
    winner = simulate_tournament(teams)
    
    if winner in counts:
        counts["winner"] += 1
    else:
        counts["winner"] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your simulate_tournament function is not returning a value.
Try with:

```
if len(teams) > 2:
    winners = simulate_round(teams)
    ganador = simulate_tournament(winners)
else:
    ganador = simulate_round(teams)
    return ganador[0]['team']

return ganador
```

i don´t know if its the most efficient function, but it worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same lab today. I think your mistake is here:
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
It should be only, with open(sys.argv[1]) as file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have keys/values inside your count variable. The reason why it is not printing anything is because there is nothing in count. Also you are not supposed to use winner as a string, the function returns a string so python automatically makes winner a string variable. You are supposed to hash the string returned for winner to the counts variable and thus update count to the correct name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding some code examples for better understanding.